# Max possible ERC20 Tokens allowed with 18 decimals?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, erc-20, tokens

I would like my token to have the maximum possible amount of tokens issued as a novelty. I would like to use 18 decimals standard ERC20 token, what value can I put in to get the maximum amount of tokens possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum number of tokens, compatible with ERC20, is the maximum amount a `uint256` variable can store: `(2**256) - 1` with `0` decimals. If you use `18` decimals, the maximum amount of tokens is `(2^256-1)/10^18 = 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,‌​665,640,564,039,457`

Comment: It should be `(2**256-1)/10**18 = 115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457`

Comment: @Ismael is that the same as (2**(256) - 1) ?

Comment: Thanks corrected it. I just wanted to make clear that he most likely isn't hitting the cap

Comment: @danielmetlitski uint256 has 256 bits of storage so the maximum number being `(2**256) - 1`. If you have one decimal you can represent at most `[(2**256) - 1] / 10` the last digit will be your decimal, repeating that reasoning you get formula in the answer.