# Given no performance penalty for maximum tokens creation. Why most tokens are not created max?

Tags: ether, erc-20

Given the answer to this question here:
[Is there a performance penalty towards creating the maximum number of tokens with ERC-20 etc?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43791/is-there-a-performance-penalty-towards-creating-the-maximum-number-of-tokens-wit)

Why are most tokens in circulation / used not created to their maximum supply possible?

Comment: The max value an `integer` can be has nothing to do with what value is represented as a token nor the business logic behind the max supply a token creator makes.

Answer (score 2):

It is a choice decided by the business design of the token.

Comparing this to Bitcoin, people usually want to own a large number of Bitcoins, not a large fraction of it. When people who don't understand finance really well try to find out the value of the Blockchain, they usually ask how much does 1 Bitcoin cost, without knowing how many Bitcoins are in circulation and what's the market cap.

It's an issue of perspective and sensation, not a limitation of technology.

I will help you if you change your question

> Why are most tokens in circulation / used not created to their maximum
>   supply possible?

to the complete opposite:

> Why are most tokens in circulation / used not created to their maximum **decimals** possible?

What if there is only 1 token released with the maximum number of decimals? How would you feel if instead of owning `12345 tokens` you would own `0,0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012345 tokens`?

The business must create a balance between functionality and perspective for possible investors.